# О семнадцати лет

Tags: предлоги

В соответствии с Толковым словарем Ушакова предлог "о" может употребляться при существительном для указания, из скольких частей, членов и т. п. состоит предмет (*стол о трех ножках. Палка о двух концах. Что ты, о двух головах, что ли?*), а также для указания неколичественного признака (*«Он явился передо мной… с длинным, желтоватым и костлявым лицом о седой бороде» Луначарский.*). А может ли этот предлог употребляться для указания возраста, например: *о семнадцати лет*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А может ли этот предлог употребляться для указания возраста, например: **о семнадцати лет**?

Немного непонятно, почему автор вопроса, приводя примеры с предлогом **о** и существительными в предложном падеже (*о двух головах* и др.), затем неожиданно перескакивает на *родительный падеж* (**о семнадцати лет**)?? Давайте не будем забывать, что предлог **о** употребляется с вин. и предл. падежами.
Родительный падеж применяется при указании возраста без предлога : *семи лет*, *сорока лет*.

> Ф. М. Достоевский. Подросток (1875)
> И поставила она их всех рядком у церковной паперти; старшему мальчику восемь годков, а остальные все девочки погодки, все мал малой меньше; **старшенькая четырех годков**, а младшая еще на руках, грудь сосет. [

С предложным падежом и предлогом **в** мы имеем известную конструкцию : "в (молодых, юных, зрелых, преклонных...) летах (годах)".

> Н. В. Гоголь. Шинель (1842)
> Акакий Акакиевич, как **человек в летах**, хотел попробовать в рукава; Петрович помог надеть и в рукава, ― вышло, что и в рукава была хороша.

Сочетание типа "о семнадцати годах" мы можем встретить в текстах в значении промежутка времени :

> Н.И. Греч. Черная женщина (1834)
> Вы помните, думаю, что я, сообщая вам историю свою, **умолчал о десяти годах** моей жизни; вы помните, что я вам говорил о нежелании моем вступить в духовное звание.

Comment: > Немного непонятно, почему автор вопроса, приводя примеры с предлогом о и существительными в предложном падеже (о двух головах и др.), затем неожиданно перескакивает на родительный падеж (о семнадцати лет)??

Да, вы правы: либо "о семнадцати летах", либо "о семнадцати годах".

Comment: Ну вот, общими усилиями создали неологизм "девушка о семнадцати годах". Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь (смайлик).

Comment: А что, будем применять)))  
"Девица - не ленивица,  
О двух ногах,  
О двух руках,  
О семнадцати годках!  
Замуж не противится,  
Без толку не мылится,  
Косу через плечо,  
Да плясать исчо!" (с)

Comment: Классно, мне нравится.

Comment: Прошу прощения за промедление. Благодарю весь коллектив за усилия, вы оказали мне неоценимую услугу.

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю. Устаревший предлог О с предложным падежом употребляется при указании на наличие чего-то у предмета, синонимичен предлогу С :о двух окошках(есть 2 окошка, с 2 окошками), о седой бороде(есть седая борода, с седой бородой), о двух концах(есть 2 конца, с 2 концами). А указание на наличие возраста - это как-то не по-русски: у меня есть 17 лет, с 17 годами.

Comment: Ах, жалко! Одним антикварным выражением меньше.

Comment: Но зато антикварно можно сказать "О семнадцатом годе "= "В семнадцатом году" (О=В)

Comment: Спасибо). То-то я помню: было что-то такое с предлогом "о".

Answer (score 1):

Вот интересно: почему устарел предлог О? Мне кажется, это связано с прагматичным направлением нашего общего развития, с желанием выразиться точнее, определеннее, безо всяких ненужных туманностей и намеков.

"Там о заре прихлынут волны...", "О рождестве была у нас пирушка...". Предлог "О" охватывал предмет со всех сторон, делал мир пространственным, а мы перешли на плоское описание: не "о заре", а "на заре". Был у нас конь "о четырех ногах" и была избушка "о куриной ножке, об одном окошке", да остались только в сказках.

А почему бы в новой литературе не возродить эти выражения? Пусть там будет девушка о семнадцати лет! И это будет не просто информация о возрасте девушки, а сообщение об особом  внутреннем состоянии нашей юной героини.

Comment: София,  у  вас  слишком  художественный  подход  к  семантике.

Comment: "Увы, такие вещи не во власти одного или даже нескольких людей, это происходит в нашем языке как бы само собой. На Украине вон проще, там язык неустоявшийся, еще и сейчас складывается,три-четыре популярных медиа-персоны за пару месяцев внедряют новые слова, или забытые диалектизмы, или обороты из эмигрантской среды во всебщее употребление.У нас не так. Кто вводил вопросительное "да?" в конце почти каждой фразы лет 15 назад, как появилось и почти исчезло "как бы" где надо и не надо - отследить и управлять такими явлениями невозможно.