# "О трёх головах" и не только

Tags: предлоги

Встречается это выражение в сказках. А где ещё предлог "о" употребляется в той же роли? Можете привести примеры? "Хвост о булаве на кончике", например, грамматически соответствует? А "рука о пяти пальцах"? А "старуха о двух вёдрах в руках"? В общем, хотелось бы понять границы и возможности этого выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечали на этот вопрос на  форуме, **даже стихи писали интересные и милые люди,** да вот ушли почему-то.

**Про девушку о семнадцати лет** [О семнадцати лет](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30874/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82/30890#30890)

А теперь кто ответит? **Ну статью найдут в словарях**, например эту:

**Устар.** Употр. при характеристике кого-, чего-л. путём указания **на количество входящих в него или составляющих его частей, деталей, элементов и т.п.** Строение о двух окнах. Дом о семи комнатах. Змей Горыныч о трёх головах. Шхуна о двух мачтах.

**Вот еще один ответ** [https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/Палка-о-двух-концах/11910#11910](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85/11910#11910)